# Pass result from onload function to variable

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

This is a module in my iPhone app. It's purpose is to return an array from a JSON responeText, which can then be added to the data property of an TableView in another module.

Being relatively new to JavaScript I can't find the right syntax to pass my array to the variable self.

```
function Events() {
var self = [];

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/ngparser/events.php');

xhr.onload = function() {
    var events = JSON.parse(this.responseText),
        rows = [];

    Ti.API.info('JSON responseText: ');
    Ti.API.info(events);

    for (var i in events) {
        var id = events[i].id,
            title = events[i].title;            

        var amp = title.search('&amp;');
        if (amp != -1) {
            title = title.replace('&amp;', '&');
        }

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: title,
            hasChild: true
        });
        rows.push(row);         
    }

    // I want this...
    return rows;        
};

xhr.send();
self = //... to end up here!
self = xhr.send(); //Does not work
return self;
}

module.exports = Events;
```

EDIT: A solution was eventually found here http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/133913/how-do-i-pass-result-from-xhronload-function-to-variable#comment-119031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xhr.onload function is running asynchronously and wont return a value, so returning the rows variable is useless.

What you can do is use the setData method of a table view inside the callback function to add the array of rows to the tableview.

```
function Events() {
var self = [];

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/ngparser/events.php');

xhr.onload = function() {
    var events = JSON.parse(this.responseText),
        rows = [];

    Ti.API.info('JSON responseText: ');
    Ti.API.info(events);

    for (var i in events) {
        var id = events[i].id,
            title = events[i].title;            

        var amp = title.search('&amp;');
        if (amp != -1) {
            title = title.replace('&amp;', '&');
        }

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: title,
            hasChild: true
        });
        rows.push(row);         
    }
    tableView.setData(rows);

};

xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: I've been playing with callbacks but can't get it to work. My eventsCallback don't seem to run, since theres no output from info(). Window Module: http://pastebin.com/1kdga075 Data Module: http://pastebin.com/bQVi55Pn

Comment: If the onload callback is not firing, then there has to be an error.  Try adding an info() into the onerror callback, and see if that is triggering.

Comment: xhr.onload in Events() is indeed firing since I get output from info() in function, I meant eventsCallback() in EventsWindow. Sorry about that. I added "xhr.onerror = function(e) {Ti.API.info(e.error);}" to Events() and there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, the `onload` function runs when the AJAX call is done.  Meaning JavaScript continues with your function, and runs `onload` later.  This means you cannot return a value from it.

You need to put all code relating to the `rows` (or `self`) variable inside the `onload` function.